# placing video files on http from my local computer

Tags: streaming, video-streaming

I am making one application in which I need to play some videos on my webpage or application.
And my videos are placed on my computer locally. Now what kind of URL i need to provide, or what type of streaming do I need to make it playable on other computers, from the webpage only.

Is there any controls, which plays videos locally on my computer and show it to the client side.??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all is your web site hosted on your computer or are using a Hosting service?

Either way

You can use either flash Plug in or Windows Media Player Plugin
(silver light is also an option, the risk is the users may not have installed it since it is fairly new)

you must configure them with the URL of the videos, so that they will be served for viewing

Eg:
while doing that place your videos in a seperate folder in the site's root folders

like /videos/video1.mpg